# looping images on internet explorer

Tags: powershell

I have created a simple image loop using IE explorer. I am having one issue with the code.

If a delete the next image on the loop I get a error `cannot find the file`.

Code:

```
$duration = 5 # duration between slides    
$repeat = 99999999 # how many times do you want to repeat the images

for ($i=0; $i -lt $repeat ; $i++) {
    $image = (Get-ChildItem C:\testing\image\*.jpg).name 

    ForEach ($imageitem in $image) {

        $ie = New-Object -COMObject InternetExplorer.Application -Property` 
                        @{Navigate2="C:\testing\image\$imageitem"; 
                        Visible = $true 
    }         
    $ie
    sleep -Seconds $duration
    $ie.Quit()
}
```

}

Comment: Ofc it gives you this error when you delete the image, what do you except / what do you want it to do?

Comment: ok, so what i want it to do. is either lockdown the file from being deleted while it is still in the loop or ignore the deleted file and move on the the next image

Comment: What are you trying to achieve anyway? Maybe there's better a way.

Comment: `if(test-path $imageitem.fullname){"showme"}else{"Icant"}`?

Comment: thanks Matt changed the code to include if (test-path) and this has solved my problem.  it now ignores if and image is deleted and opens the next available image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i amended the code:

```
$duration= 5 # duration between slides
$repeat=99999999 # how many times do you want to repeat the images
for ( $i=0; $i -lt $repeat ; $i++){
  $image=(Get-ChildItem C:\testing\image\*.jpg).FullName
  ForEach ($imageitem in $image){
    if(test-path $imageitem){
      $ie=new-Object -COMObject InternetExplorer.Application -Property @{Navigate2= $imageitem; Visible = $true}
      $ie
      sleep -Seconds $duration
      $ie.Quit()
    }
  }
}
```